# Regex for matching a pattern which only needs to start with a valid sequence start

Tags: objective-c, swift, regex

I have this regex pattern here `/^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$/`. It's for validating HH:MM 24-hour strings with optional leading zero.

However, when I match this against the string `23:59`, for example, it works. That's a good thing. But I would like to also match these strings: `2`, `23`, `23:`, `23:5` and `23:59`. After hours and hours of debugging, I still couldn't look for something like this, if it exists.

(If it's useful, I'm using the Objective-C regex engine, or optionally I can use the Swift one as well.)

Comment: Would `07` be valid for example and even `00`?

Comment: @JvdV Matched against this pattern I posted, no, it wouldn't. But matched against this hypothetical pattern, it should be. 00 should be valid also.

Comment: @JvdV why it shouldn't be? It's a 24-hour time format. But with this regex pattern I posted it shouldn't be a match. It has a different, but close application compared to what I need. In a hypothetical pattern, 2 should be a match. And also 1 and 0 (and others).

Comment: Typically the format for `H:MM` would allow for single digit, but in a `HH:MM` format this would always be two digits. That's why I asked.

Comment: As I said, it's a HH:MM with an optional leading zero. HH:MM with required leading zero is a different thing, so is H:MM (without zero)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Thefourthbird! Regex works very well, but I noticed that an alone '4' or any number besides '0', '1' and '2' (the ones that should be matching) is matching as well. Could you try to fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start the match with a digit 00-23 or and make the all the minute parts optional.

```
^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(?::(?:[0-5][0-9]?)?)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[01]?[0-9]` Match from 00 - 19 or 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `2[0-3]` match 20-23
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `:` Match a `:` char
  - `(?:[0-5][0-9]?)?` Optionally match 5 and an optional digit 0-9
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lKD5km/1)

Comment: I like it, but it makes no sense to me that `05:9` should match (because of the full sequence of `05:9M` as per OP's comment below my answer), but `9:15` should not match.....

Comment: @JvdV Hmm..I have added another pattern to match minutes 0-9.

Comment: Therefor I also don't understand why a standalone number above 3 shouldn't be matched.....

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! But '23:69' matches as well, which is what I don't want.

Comment: @TimotejLeginus Like this? https://regex101.com/r/KLir6t/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you very much! It works well, except for example it should match '4:49' as well. But, good enough.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Referring to your latest message now, it also matches '23:6' which I don't want as well. Thanks

Comment: @TimotejLeginus How come you want to match `05:9` but not `23:6`?

Comment: Oh. I completely missed that 9 is over 6. My brain just skipped a brainbeat lol. I don't want to match 05:9, only 05:09, I don't want to match 23:6, only 23:06. Sorry 

Comment: @TimotejLeginus So this would be it then? https://regex101.com/r/lKD5km/1

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the following could work:

```
^(?:[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])(?::(?:[0-5]?[0-9])?)?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zbDvQA/1)

- `^` - Start string anchor.
- `(?:` - Open 1st non-capture group:

  - `[01]?` - Optional zero or one;
  - `[0-9]` - Any digit;
  - `|` - Or:
  - `2[0-3]` - A two followed by a numer ranging from zero to three;
  - `)` - Close 1st non-capture group.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group:

  - `:` - A colon;
  - `(?:` - Open 3rd non-capture group:

    - `[0-5]?[0-9]` - Optional number from zero to five and a number from zero to nine;
    - `)?` - Close 3rd non-capture group and make it optional.
  - `)?` - Close 2nd non-capture group and make it optional.
- `$` - End string anchor.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation, but I found out that '23:6' matches as well, which shouldn't be matched.